# firebase listen method don't trigger

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream-builder

Hi i am facing a problem with SteamBuilder , i tried different method of fetching data that works but don't auto refresh when new data are available in FireBase.
Below my SteamBuilder source code :

```
@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
messageRef
.where('chatId', isEqualTo: widget.chatId)
.limit(_limit)
.orderBy('time', descending: true)
.snapshots()
.listen((event) {
_localStreamController.sink.add(event);
}, onDone: () {
print("data done");
}, onError: (err) {
print("error : " + err.toString());
}, cancelOnError: false);
}

StreamController<QuerySnapshot> _localStreamController =
StreamController.broadcast();

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
stream: _localStreamController.stream,
builder: (BuildContext context,
    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  //This value changes
  if (!(snapshot.connectionState ==
          ConnectionState.active &&
      snapshot.hasData)) {
    print("no data");
    return SizedBox(
      height: 0,
    );
  }
  List<Message> messages = [];
  var items = snapshot.data.documents;
  for (var item in items) {
    messages.add(
        Message.fromDoc(item, widget.currentUserId));
  }
  _messages = messages;
  return ListView.builder(
    reverse: true,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
    itemCount: messages.length,
    controller: listScrollController,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      final Message message = messages[index];
      final bool isMe = message.sender.id == null;
      return _buildMessage(message, isMe);
    },
  );
})),
void sendMessage(String message,String currentUserId, User receiver,String chatId )    {
messageRef.add({
'chatId': chatId,
'sender': User.toDoc(await DatabaseService.getUserWithId(currentUserId)),
'text': message,
'receiver': User.toDoc(receiver),
'isLiked': false,
'unread': false,
'time': Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now())
});
}
```

So when i trigger sendMessage, the ".listen()" method don't work on new data.

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I was missing the firebase index on some properties , so i changed .snapshots() to .getDocuments() to be able to get the link to create the missing indexes.
Then i rebuild with .snapshots() and it worked like a charm

Comment: Do you create your StreamBuilder in initState() ?

Comment: @Mäddin no in Widget build(BuildContext context) but i already solved the problem (look at mi EDIT:) , thank you